# Uart for Atmega32

Tags: uart

Can manchester encoding be implemented using UART?

If not what kind of modulation can I use, using UART on the Atmega32. I am making a Visible Light Comm system. If I use the UART as normal I get flickering of the LED, because there are long strings of zero's and one's. I want to use UART because Im finding it hard to design my own communication protocol. But I need to find a way to modulate my data using UART.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> If I use the UART as normal I get flickering of the LED

If data rate isn't an issue and you're just trying to deal with visible flickering, you could consider sending two bytes instead of one.

That is, instead of

```
transmitbyte(x)
```

Do

```
transmitbyte(lo(x));
transmitbyte(hi(x));
```

Where `lo(x)` interleaves the bottom 4 bits with their inverses, like Manchester. So bits `hgfedcba` => `DdCcBbAa`, where `A` is inverse of bit `a`; `hi(x)` takes `hgfedcba` => `HhGgFfEe`.  Thus you'll get a transition every bit time.  If the receiver feels like it, it could check the consistency of each byte.

If you don't have any other way to stay in sync, send `lo(x)&0x7f` and `hi(x)|0x80`.

You'll see that if you transmit back-to-back at 8N1, taking account of the start and stop bits, you'll have the same number of 1s and 0s in the output, one of the main benefits of Manchester encoding.  Additionally you have a guaranteed transition within two bits.

```
0DdCcBbAa10HhGgFfEe1
```

Or if you use the high bit to say which nibble this is, then you still have equal 1s and 0s, and a transition guaranteed within three bits.

```
00dCcBbAa101hGgFfEe1
```

Comment: that is quite an interesting idea. Will definitely try it. @jonathanjo

Comment: let us know how you get on.

Comment: I decided to see which ascii values had 3 or more consecutive 0's in them or 1's like A,B,C,a,b and so on and just change them to a different value, because after testing and a lot of testing I realised 3 0's or 1's caused flickering. Simple and eassssyy solution. Thanks to you but. @jonathanjo

Comment: If you don't need a general solution, that seems an excellent way around the flickering problem.

Answer (score 1):

> Can manchester encoding be implemented using UART?

Not usually.

> If not what kind of modulation can I use

Manchester encoding in its basic form "mixes" the data stream (from a UART for example) with a clock associated with that data. It "mixes" by using an exclusive OR gate and, providing you successfully extract the clock from the manchester encoded data in your receiver you can use another exclusive OR gate to extract the data.

It's a very related to a baseband signal and a carrier wave for an RF system. What gets produced is the baseband signal but raised up in frequency to form a spectrum around the carrier wave frequency.

You don't have to use the data clock. For instance, if you choose an arbitrarily high clock (much higher than the data rate) you can still use an EXOR to produce modulated data and decode the same way.

Alternatively you can use a data scrambler - this uses a series of flip flops and EXOR gates to remove the long lengths of zeros or ones. Pretty much the same circuit can be used to unscramble the data in the receiver.

Comment: What sort of modulation does UART use?

Comment: A UART converts a parallel data byte to a serial data byte by sequentially transmitting the bits. A start and stop bit is added to "package" the byte to be sent. A UART can also do the reverse action when receiving. It's a big subject that you should read about. There are tons of stuff on the internet and, if something confuses you, please raise a new question.

Answer (score 0):

If you connect an LED (and suitable resistor) between the UART output pin and Ground, the LED WILL flicker as the UART output toggles between high and low levels.

Whether you can see this flicker or not depends on the UART data rate, and the bit pattern it is sending.  If the LED didn't flicker, you couldn't send any data using the light from the LED.

Comment: the LED does flicker but its at a frequency the human eye cannot detect. @PeterBennett